# Logstash can't write output file

Tags: logstash

I want to write output file on logstash, but logstash can't write file. file is empty and i can see logs on Kibana Dashboard.
My output.conf file ;

```
output {
 file {
   path => "/home/freed/example.txt"
   codec => line { format => "custom format: %{message}"}
 }
}
```

I want to help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that you have problems accessing (permission) the file for the logstash.

Check you log: `/var/log/logstash/logstash-plain.log`

In you example logstash must have accessing to `/home/freed` and be the owner file `example.txt`

Comment: I solved problem but your answer is true so i you check , thank u